# How to clear a zombie process whose parent is init (PID 1)?

Tags: linux, process

According to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944886/how-to-kill-zombie-process

In order to clean a zombie process I should kill its parent.

In my case the parent is PID 1 (init). Which according to: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7441/can-root-kill-init-process

can't be killed. (even if it could be killed, I'm not sure it's such a good idea)

```
root@localhost:~# ps -ef | grep bcmrm
root     16772 30829  0 22:47 pts/8    00:00:00 grep bcmrm
root     21272     1  0 Jan26 ?        00:00:02 [bcmrm] <defunct>
```

What are my options? And why didn't init process cleaned it up?

Thanks,

Comment: This may also help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310768/.

Comment: I had [the same problem](https://superuser.com/q/388565/83694) 7 years ago, except the zombie process was using 100% of a CPU core.  My issue was likely a driver bug, and until the vendor fixed their driver, my workaround was to reboot the machine.